# Range of $f\in C_c(X)$ is compact subset of complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The collection of all continuous complex functions on $X$ whose support is compact is denoted by $C_c(X)$.

[image]

Book's proof is quite not detailed and I will write a detailed proof.

**Proof:** Let $f\in C_c(X)$ with compact support $K$. Then it's easy to show that $f(X)\subset f(K)\cup \{0\}$.
If $X$ is compact then $f(X)$ is also compact by 2.10 Theorem.

Suppose that $X$ is NOT compact. Then $\{0\}\in f(X)$ since otherwise $X=\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}$ and we get that $K=X$ which is contradiction because $X$ is not compact. Since $K\subset X$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(K)\subset f(X)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(K)\cup \{0\}\subset f(X)\cup \{0\}=f(X).$ We get that $$f(K)\cup \{0\}= f(X).$$

Since $\{0\}$ is compact then $f(X)$ is also compact since it's union of finite number of compact.

Can anyone check my proof please?

Comment: Your proof is perfect: there is only a little imprecision: it's $\{ 0\} \subset f(X)$, not $\{ 0 \} \in f(X)$.

Comment: @Crostul, Why Rudin wrote that $0\in f(X)$?

Comment: $0$ is an element of $\mathbb{C}$. $\{0\}$ is the subset of $\mathbb{C}$ containing the element $0$ alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct but verbose. Since it's either $f(X) = f(K)$ or $f(X) = f(K) \cup \{0\}$, you only need to show that both $f(K)$ and $f(K)\cup \{0\}$ are compact.

You seem to have asked quite a few questions on proof verification. It might be a good practice for you to take time verifying your own proof, and explain the part you feel dubious about.

Comment: But in both cases $f(K)$ and $f(K)\cup \{0\}$ are compact. In first case, since $f$ - continuous and $K$-compact $\Rightarrow$ $f(K)$-compact. In second case, $\{0\}$ is compact since it's one-point set $\Rightarrow$ finite union of compact sets also compact $\Rightarrow$ $f(K)\cup \{0\}$ - compact. Am I right? In fact, I wrote these reasoning in above question.

Comment: Sorry to remind you once again. But Am I right?

Comment: As others have mentioned, you are correct. Be more confident in your own logic.

Comment: But you said that i need to show that both .... This little bit confuses me since I have showed that above

Comment: I was saying that you don't need the "suppose $X$ is not compact..." stuff. Just stick to the range. A correct proof is good. A clean proof is even better.

Comment: This case is important for showing that $\{0\}\in f(X)$

Comment: First of all, it's $\{0\}\subset f(X)$. Second, whether $0\in f(X)$ or not is completely irrelevant, because the range will always be compact, i.e., $f(K)\subset f(X)\subset f(K)\cup \{0\}$. This fact is independent of the nature of $X$. Then why bother discussing $X$ at all?

Comment: Yes! You're right!